# Mac OS application data folders using FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

In Windows I use CSIDL_APPDATA folder to store the application data for the current user
and C_CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA for all users application data (shared data).

In Mac OS I would use:

```
~/Library/Application Support/YourApp = Application data for the current user
/Library/Application Support/YourApp = Application data for all users
```

("~" = home directory of the user)

How can I get the above Mac OS folders using FireMonkey?

Answer (score 3):

Part of your question: Application data for current user = [GetHomePath](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.GetHomePath)

Comment: I do the above, then just hard code the rest of the path. Wrap it in `{$IFDEF MACOS}{$ENDIF}` and you're good to go.